# Facebook send API meta tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata

I'm trying to invite a friend to my application, which I'm sending a message to him saying to join this game.

Here is the code which triggers the function.

```
function invitefbfriends(){
      FB.init({appId: 'XXX', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          link: 'http://example.com/game/1',
        });
      }
```

Why is this picking wrong meta data?

I've meta tags in the respective page, but this is picking the meta tags from the http://example.com/ which is a index page

Comment: Can you please share with us the real URL so that we can check it against the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)?

Comment: both these urls http://domain.com and http://domain.com/game/1 is picking the same meta tags - I checked that with facebook debugger

Comment: Lix, the url is http://2challenges.com and the challenge page is http://2challenges.com/challenge/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user reaches your inner URL (`.../game/1`) and is not logged in, they are redirected to the root URL and presented with a login screen.

The same exact thing will happen to Facebook's crawlers when they reach that URL. They are not a logged in user so they are redirected to the login page (on your root URL) and are presented with the `og:tags` on that page.

What you can do to circumvent this behavior is somehow detect whether it is a "real" user requesting the page or one of Facebook's crawler bots. You can do this in two ways:

1. Detect one of Facebook's known IPs. There is a list [on this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#crawl) as well as a CLI command to extract the current list of IPs.
2. Detect Facebook's user agent string (also mentioned in the above link). This method is not too recommended because it is relatively easy to spoof a user agent.

Once you have detected that the request is coming from Facebook, you'll need to let that request bypass your authentication system or just provide a page with the correct `og:tag` information.

Comment: Lix, Can't we create a page something like http://domainname.com/meta which will only have metadata. Which doesn't have any login authentication. This way facebook can crawl the metadata and pull it

Comment: Sure! That sounds like a great idea. Something like `og.php` that takes the URL, decides what resource was supposed to be displayed and instead just display the meta `og:tag` information. That sounds like the right way to proceed.

Comment: Will this work,coz i still see facebook is still getting metadata from home page

Comment: See the results of [passing your URL through the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F2challenges.com%2Fchallenge%2F3). There are still redirects happening. You can use this tool to test your Facebook bot detection. Once it's working, you'll see the correct `og:tag` values there.